# Is this the subgroup lattice for $\Bbb{Z}_4 \times \Bbb{Z}_8$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, integer-lattices

I have been attempting to create the subgroup lattice for $\Bbb{Z}_4 \times \Bbb{Z}_8$. I have, so far, this: http://www.scribd.com/doc/223680804/Subgroup-Lattice-of-Z-4-x-Z-8

While I have calculated every single subgroup by hand in order to create this lattice, my intuition tells me that something is off because the top of the lattice doesn't seem symmetrical to the bottom nor are is the left half a mirror of the right half. While this isn't necessarily a requirement, most subgroup lattices of $\Bbb{Z}_m \times \Bbb{Z}_n$ I've encountered look more symmetrical than this.

Can anyone verify that this is correct or show me where my error is located?

EDIT: I have edited the subgroup lattice to include all isomorphisms. If anyone wants me to provide any further information pertaining to my lattice, just ask and I shall post it.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have missed the difference between $\Bbb Z_k$ and a general abelian group of order $k$. For instance, $\Bbb Z_8\times\Bbb Z_4$ does indeed have seven subgroups of order $4$, but one of them (the middle dot on your $\Bbb Z_4$-row) is actually $\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_2$, not $\Bbb Z_4$. Similarly, only four of your $\Bbb Z_8$s are really $\Bbb Z_8$s - the other three are $\Bbb Z_4\times\Bbb Z_2$. There are two (not three) subgroups isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_8\times\Bbb Z_2$, and none isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_{16}$ (since that group has an element of order $16$, but $\Bbb Z_8\times\Bbb Z_4$ doesn't).

Once you rethink the subgroups accordingly, you should be able to get a more accurate subgroup lattice. It definitely won't be symmetric top-to-bottom. Whether it's symmetric left-to-right might be an artifact of how you draw it.

Comment: I knew about the $\Bbb{Z}_2\times\Bbb{Z}_2$ and the $\Bbb{Z}_4\times\Bbb{Z}_2$ subgroups in the lattice (and since they were in the interior, I did not bother labeling them). However, I never bothered to check to see if $\Bbb{Z}_{16}$ was actually isomorphic. And as you point out, it isn't: it's actually $\Bbb{Z}_8\times\Bbb{Z}_2$. But be that as it may, I did not use these isomorphisms to construct the lattice. Instead, I literally wrote out all the subgroups and drew the lattice by hand. My questions remains: Is my current lattice incorrect after replacing with $\Bbb{Z}_8\times\Bbb{Z}_2$?

Comment: I reposted my lattice. This time, I filled in all the proper isomorphisms instead of having dots represent a subgroup. I hope this makes my question more "readable." Or rather, if there is a mistake in there, it is easier to find.

Comment: How did you know, right off the bat, what specific subgroups were? For example, you knew right away that the middle dot in the '4 element' row was actually $\Bbb{Z}_2\times\Bbb{Z}_2$ and not $\Bbb{Z}_4$? _I_ knew this because I sat down for an hour to figure it out, but _you knew right away!_ Is there some general technique I am missing that helps with explicitly calculating subgroups and generating lattices?

Comment: Good question! Note that $\Bbb Z_4$ contains only one element of order $2$, while $\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_2$ contains three elements of order $2$. That's how I knew that the center dot (which had three lines descending from it) was the $\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_2$. You should be able to tell similarly which of the subgroups in your diagram are $\Bbb Z_8$ and which are $\Bbb Z_4\times\Bbb Z_2$. But I don't know of an easy algorithm for computing the subgroup lattice, even for finite abelian groups (although there is a known formula for how many subgroups there are isomorphic to any given group).